# Simple CSS Width Issue

Tags: html, css

i AM new to web development (1 month) and for some reason, a simple CSS issue i am finding hard to understand.

I have 2 DIVs:

```
<div class="full">

    <div class="banner">
        My Company logo/slogan
    </div>

</div>
```

With CSS:

```
.full {
    width: 100%;
}

.banner {
    background: red;
    height: 45px;
}
```

What i don't understanding is, why does DIV with banner not consume the entire page width? Even though its parent, full, has `width: 100%` ??

I have had to apply `margin-left` and `right` to take full width e.g:

http://jsfiddle.net/4eaGv/2/

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is related with the *User agent styles* which every browser applies to the html elements by default. To avoid it we need to reset these values. Like in your case you need to reset these values for body element

```
body
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Now try your code. it will work.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4eaGv/5/)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and demo, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the browser applies padding inside a frame. You can overcome this by using a CSS Reset. In your case, simply adding  `* { padding: 0; margin: 0 }` works.

http://jsfiddle.net/4eaGv/6/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `width` on the banner div to 100%

```
.banner {
    background: red;
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And if you have some padding, set the padding and margin to html/body to 0.

```
body
{
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4eaGv/4/

Answer (score 0):

All browsers inherently give certain elements styling.

Just add this CSS to your code :

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

Some people leave out border, but I like to put it in because I find IE often adds a border to certain `<a>` elements

### Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4eaGv/3/

Answer (score 0):

Web pages by default have a little margin/padding. Most CSS starts with:

```
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0}
```

By the way, if you did that, divs automatically expand to fit their parent containers, i.e. 100% width wouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the body.

```
body {

margin : 0px !important;
 padding : 0px !important;
}
```

With your existing css.